# Automation of task which envolve exe's?

Tags: macros, automation, task, exe

Stack ! :)

**I want a program that will perform repetitive task on using 3 software.**

I am using 3 programs often. The jigsaw puzzle creator http://www.tibo.cz/archive/jppcrtr.exe  and Padgen http://pad.asp-software.org to often to create pad files and This is very labor extensive. Is there a way on how I can automatic this 2 programs using Linux Shell programming or any kind program that will accomplish the task?

I am creating dozens of jigsaw puzzle, pad files and submit these to download sites everyday, why? - for backlinking purpose.

I need to complete these files before submission, one folder contain:
.exe file – the jigsaw puzzle created using the jigsaw puzzle creator
jigsaw image – solved image-jpg of the puzzle
.xml file – created using the  PADGen(from second link)

How I am doing the Task Manually:

Step 1. Open the jigsaw puzzle creator– enter information, select Image (for the jigsaw puzzle) and generate the exe file which is the jigsaw puzzle. 
I am creating 1 jigsaw puzzle for 1 keyword I use to optimize.

Step 2. Open PADGen(from second link)– Enter info on different fields then generate .exe
Step 3. FTP the files to server or the download page.
Step 4. Open my Software submission software (Pad Worker) to submit the xml.
Step 5. Log-in to the email used to confirm submission.

## Step 1 to 5 usually took me 1 hour max.

The fields of those software the jigsaw puzzle and  PADGen are the same. The data are the only one that varies so Automation is doable.

Here is How I look into How the Macro Software Will Work.

I will input let say, 1000 keywords.

1. The Macro software will run and create 1000 folders containing (.exe file, jigsaw image and .xml file).
2. The Macro got a built in ftp client and will ftp the folder created.
3. It will open the pad worker and start submission. Here, must have settings on frequency submission so not to get banned by download sites. Pad Worker Software will run on proxies.
4. Log-in to the email account that was used for that certain pad and confirm submission and delete confirmed email.

Is this doable? thanks

This are my client's requirements.is this can be done.if yes then please guide me.If not then please provide reasons why not.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the best package for you to use would be Automation Anywhere.
You can record your actions, processes, etc. Easy to create a repeatable task and then you can schedule it to run on your schedule. Very flexible.

Let me know if you need more info. 
Good luck!
Tom

Comment: hey thanks for the reply!
But can't it be done using command line ..like using shell script in linux ?